# Lint abort when use Adaptive icon

Tags: android, lint, android-8.0-oreo

I tried Android8.0 Adaptive icons.
But i caught lint error below...

```
src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml: Error: 
Launcher icons must be in PNG format [IconLauncherFormat]  


Explanation for issues of type "IconLauncherFormat":
Launcher icons should be in the PNG format. This requirement is enforced by
the The Google Play Developer Console.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size
```

How to resolve this? 
Is it only possible to disable with LintOption?

Please help. thanks.

Comment: Maybe you just have to update Android Studio and the Android plugin to 3.0.0.

Comment: thanks! "Icon Launcher Format" was disabled in AS3.0.
And an error occurred when suppressed in AS3.0.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this to your **app/build.gradle** file, in the **android** section:

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")
}
```

and then, create the file app/lint.xml with the following contents:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="IconLauncherFormat">
        <ignore path="src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```